# How to use multiple certificates as a web service client - spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I have a spring boot 2.0.0 application as a backend along with angular 6 frontend application.

The angular app calls the spring rest apis in https (ssl) and at the same time the backend spring app calls an external systems in https.

I use this configuration to define the ssl certificate:

```
server.ssl.key-store=C:\\path\\to\\certificate.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=pass
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=myalias
```

also I found this piece of code in an old project while application initialization :

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", env.getProperty("app.ws.JKSFileName"));
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",env.getProperty("app.ws.JKSFilePassword"));
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
```

The application now works fine and https is applied with both FE and external systems

Now I have some questions :

1- Are the two parts doing the same functionality but the first is the new way (through configuration only) and the other is an old way .. or they do different things?

2- Is this part used while the frontend communicates with the spring app or when the spring app calls the external systems - as I understand , it's for the frontend ... but my master insists that it's for calling the external systems (the second code portion at least which exists in old systems)

3- Now I need to call new external systems that use different certificates ( x509 certificate) ... so I need to configure my application to use a certain one at a time .. I don't know how to fulfill this .. according to both codes the configuration is done at the application level